# Incremental Data loading and Querying in Pyspark without restarting Spark JOB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi All I want to do incremental data query.

```
  df = spark .read.csv('csvFile', header=True)  #1000 Rows
  df.persist() #Assume it takes 5 min
  df.registerTempTable('data_table') #or createOrReplaceTempView
  result = spark.sql('select * from data_table where column1 > 10') #100 rows
  df_incremental  = spark.read.csv('incremental.csv') #200 Rows
  df_combined = df.unionAll(df_incremental)
  df_combined.persist() #It will take morethan 5 mins, I want to avoid this, because other queries might be running at this time
  df_combined.registerTempTable("data_table")
  result = spark.sql('select * from data_table where column1 > 10') # 105 Rows.
```

1. read a csv/mysql Table data into spark dataframe.
2. Persist that dataframe in memory Only(reason: I need performance & My dataset can fit to memory)
3. Register as temp table and run spark sql queries. #Till this my spark job is UP and RUNNING.
4. Next day i will receive a incremental Dataset(in a temp_mysql_table or a csv file). Now I want to run same query on a Total set i:e persisted_prevData + recent_read_IncrementalData.  i will call it mixedDataset.
   *** there is no certainty that when incremental data comes to system, it can come 30 times a day.
5. Till here also I don't want the spark-Application to be down,. It should always be Up. And I need performance of querying mixedDataset with same time measure as if it is persisted.

My Concerns :

1. In P4,  Do i need to unpersist the prev_data and again persist the union-Dataframe of prev&Incremantal data?
2. And my most important concern is i don't want to restart the Spark-JOB to load/start with Updated Data(Only if server went down, i have to restart of course).

So, on a high level, i need to query (faster performance) dataset + Incremnatal_data_if_any dynamically.

Currently i am doing this exercise by creating a folder for all the data, and incremental file also placed in the same directory. Every 2-3 hrs, i am restarting the server and my sparkApp starts with reading all the csv files present in that system. Then queries running on them.

And trying to explore hive persistentTable and Spark Streaming, will update here if found any result.

Please suggest me a way/architecture to achieve this.

Please comment, if anything is not clear on Question, without downvoting it :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try streaming instead it will be much faster since the session is already running and it will be triggered everytime you place something in the folder:

```py
df_incremental = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("sep", ",") \
    .schema(input_schema) \
    .csv(input_path)

df_incremental.where("column1 > 10") \
    .writeStream \
    .queryName("data_table") \
    .format("memory") \
    .start()

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM data_table).show()
```